# alternative to connect to domain on windows 7 home edition

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1, domain, active-directory, windows-domain

I know that it is Impossible to join a domian, But I was wondering if a 3rd party software is available that can hellp me.
The only function I need is to have to user folder on the server.
Thank you.

Comment: anything at all out there?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to join a computer to domain in order to access a folder shared from an AD domain.  As long as you have a user on the domain with share and file access permissions to that folder, then you can use that user's credentials to access the folder.  You can map a network drive to that folder, using the credentials of the domain user.

Comment: Yes, That I know, but I want the user profile folder (c:\users\my_user)
To be on the server